# Can React Native store a large amount of information

Tags: reactjs, react-native, sqlite, local-storage, asyncstorage

I want to store 100000 record in my application so i can use it in offline mod first I try to use `Asyncstorage`

```
try{
 await AsyncStorage.setItem(@Devices, JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

but I have problem when I try to get the saved data

```
      let Devices = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@Devices');

      let newList = await JSON.parse( Devices );
```

`AsyncStorage` throw error :

> AsyncStorage Couldn't read row 0, col 0 from CursorWindow

then I try to use `react-native-sqlite-storage` I face problem where

I have a problem that the data must be added one by one (for loop to insert 100000 record) and this led to the application being stuck

```
  // Didmount
  useEffect(() => {
    createTable();
  });

  const createTable = () => {
    db.transaction(tx => {
      tx.executeSql(
        'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS' +
          'USERS' +
          '(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,item_code TEXT,item_desc TEXT,ser_id TEXT,inv_no TEXT,status TEXT,location TEXT,)',
      );
    });
  };



  const insertIntoTable = () => {

    deviceList.map(item=>{
      db.transaction(tx => {
        tx.executeSql(
          'INSERT INTO USERS (item_code,item_desc,ser_id,inv_no,status,location) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,)',
          [item.item_code, item.item_desc, item.ser_id, iitem.nv_no, item.status, item.location],
        );
      });
    })

  };
```

Comment: can you share code used for sqlite

Comment: @MeisamSaba i add the code

Answer (score 0):

you have to call `transaction` at first ,and define loop in , it's something like this :

```
 try {
    db.transaction(
      tx => {
        deviceList.forEach(async item => {
          await tx.executeSql(
            'INSERT INTO USERS (item_code,item_desc,ser_id,inv_no,status,location) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,)',
            [item.item_code, item.item_desc, item.ser_id, iitem.nv_no, item.status, item.location],
        );
        });
      },
      null,
      null,
    );
  } catch (error) {
    result = false;
  }
```

maybe it's Helpful :)

Comment: Thank you, but this process takes a lot of time more than 3 minutes  and then the app is stuck and i can't tell user to wait 3 minutes to open the app

Comment: Are you sure test my answer sample code ? I Tried 20,000 record in 20sec

Comment: even 20 seconds is a lot, in my case maybe the data is too large around 100000 record . Also, do not forget the capabilities of the phone. I usually work on an old phone

Comment: Thank you for your helping i already fix the problem you can see my solution and it is very fast it take 6 sec to save the data

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by dividing the data into 10,000 for each one, so the 100,000 divided into 10 AsyncStorage

```
     let loop = (await res.items.length) / 10000;

        let loop2 = (await loop) % 1 === 0 ? loop : parseInt(loop) + 1;
        let first = -10000;
        let second = 0;
        let last = res.items.length;
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('loop', loop2.toString());

        for (var i = 0; i < loop2; i++) {
          first = first + 10000;
          second = i + 1 == loop2 ? last : second + 10000;
          let data = await res.items.slice(first, second);

          try {
            let Device = await ('@Device' + i + 1);
            await AsyncStorage.setItem(Device, JSON.stringify(data));

         
            if (i + 1 == loop2) {
              setIsLoading(false);
            }
```